# How to align table content HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am working in HTML for a project. Need help in aligning two tables. 
Table One contains table head and table two contains table body.
How to align both the table synchronously.

Here is the code:

```
<body>

<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  </table>
  <table>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</body>
```

[Here is the Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/j8soLnxq/1/)

Comment: Why do you have _two_ tables in first place? Make it one table (remove `</table><table>` in the middle) and it should be fine & aligned!

Comment: @R.J. Aravind , you have a question with 4 different answers. None of these really solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Closing your *table* tag and open it again will create two differents tables, so the tables will not be aligned. To do the *"align"* of your items you need to create both `<thead>` and `<tbody>` in the same table, as you can see below:

```html
    <body>

    <h2>HTML Table</h2>
    
    <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
    
      <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    
    </body>
```

Comment: @cmprogram I've edited the answer, thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Here i am freezing the table head while scrolling, so that i need two tables ,one for table head and another for table body.Now i want to align the table body corresponding to the table head @cmprogram

Answer (score 0):

First you need to fix your table html (I've done so below). Also in `<tables>`'s you control column widths from within the `<th>`'s.

So it would be like this:

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.company { width: auto; }
.contact { width: auto; }
.country { width: 100px; }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="company">Company</th>
      <th class="contact">Contact</th>
      <th class="country">Country</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Here i am freezing the table head while scrolling, so that i need two tables ,one for table head and another for table body.Now i want to align the table body corresponding to the table head @Oneezy

Comment: In that case it might be a better option for you to use something like the Data Tables library https://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can change everything to div and deal with it. It grants more control about your style and code. As above:

```css
body {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.table-wrapper {
  display: table;
}

.table-header {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #CCC;
}

.table-row,
.table-header {
  display: table-row;
}

.table-row:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.table-row>div,
.table-header>div {
  display: table-cell;
}

.table-wrapper,
.table-row>div,
.table-header>div {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <h2>HTML Table</h2>

  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="table-header">
      <div>Company</div>
      <div>Contact</div>
      <div>Country</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div>Alfreds Futterkiste</div>
      <div>Maria Anders</div>
      <div>Germany</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div>Alfreds Futterkiste</div>
      <div>Maria Anders</div>
      <div>Germany</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

@R.J. Aravind: Edited post check it out.

```css
table {
     font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    display: contents;
}

td, th {
 border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 500px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
h2 {text-align: center; }
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

  <table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions,I Need table to be aligned subsequently. @Asiya Fathima

Comment: I tried to freeze the table head, it worked. but when i use few of your css code  to align the table content it is not working. Please check in the below url  @Asiya Fathima               
http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/fj8wM/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>

<table style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>COMPANY</th>
      <th>CONTACT</th>
      <th>COUNTRY</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>alfreds</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>alfreds</td>
      <td>Maria Anders</td>
      <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML table</title>
</head>
<body>
 <table border="5" align="center" bgcolor="pink" width="30%">
            <Thead>
                <Tr bgcolor="yellow">
                    <Th>ID</Th>
                    <Th>Name</Th>
                    <Th>Branch</Th>
                    <Th colspan="2">Skillset</Th>
                    
                </Tr>
            </Thead>
        </body>
            <Tbody>
                <Tr>
                    <Td>201</Td>
                    <Td>Sam</Td>
                    <Td rowspan="2">CSE</Td>
                    <Td>CSS</Td>
                    <Td>html</Td>
                </Tr>
    
                    <Tr>
                        <Td>202</Td>
                        <Td>Jack</Td>
                        <Td>Java</Td>
                        <Td>J2EE</Td>
                    </Tr>
                
                
                        <Tr>
                            <Td>203</Td>
                            <Td>Harsh</Td>
                            <Td>Mech</Td>
                            <Td>TDrilling</Td>
                            <Td>Java</Td>
                        </Tr>
                    
                    
                            <Tr>
                                <Td>204</Td>
                                <Td>Ryan</Td>
                                <Td>ECE</Td>
                                <Td>Java</Td>
                                <Td>Python</Td>
                            </Tr>
                        </Tbody>
        </table>
        </html>
```